# JSON.stringify array resulting in double brackets

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

```
var DTO = [];

$.each(data.Foobars, function(i, val){
    DTO.push(val);
});

//example of a stringified object in the array:
// var val = {"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"};

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(DTO);
```

With one object in the array the ´jsonString´ would look like:

```
[{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"}]
```

With more than one:

```
[[{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"}, {"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"}]]
```

Resulting in double brackets, which is causing me some problems serverside.

How can i get rid of the double brackets? Thanks

Comment: Causing you more problems server-side? The `JavaScriptSerializer` should have no problems with that :)

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(DTO)`?

Comment: @mattytommo im using JSON.net and it has some problems with it.

Comment: @Jack Yes, you see the stringified versions above

Comment: @Johan that's what comes from `JSON.stringify()`; but have you inspected the value of `DTO` on the console?

Comment: @Jack Yes, its an array. But it has double brackets as well. I suppose thats not how its supposed to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure the `val` object is not an array itself?

In my little test: http://jsfiddle.net/NatJS/, JSON.stringify works just fine.

**Update:** if `val` is an array, you need to treat it appropriately, such as: http://jsfiddle.net/NatJS/1/

```
var a = [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3},{ d: 10, e: 11, f: 12}];
//var a = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
var j = [];


if (a.length) { // cheap way to check if a an an array; implement something like mooTools.typeOf if you want something more robust
    while (a.length > 0) {
        j.push(a.pop());               
    }
}
else {
    j.push(a);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(j));​
```

Comment: See me update above, you should check for the type of `val` and treat it appropriately. If you're pushing an array into an array, JSON.stringify behaves exactly like it should :)

Comment: I used typeof to check if it was an array. Should have used $.isArray. Solved it with jquerys $.makeArray (only makes one if necessary). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The comment area is too small for this.

Take a look at the following simplification of your problem:

```
var DTO = [];

DTO.push({"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"});
DTO.push({"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"});

console.log(JSON.stringify(DTO));
```

It will show:

```
[{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"},{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"}]
```

Conclusion: whatever you think `val` should contain it's not ;-)

Comment: My problem seems to be that if data.Foobars.length == 1 then val will contains the values of the object. 1,2,3. But if there are more than one object, val will be the entire object...

Answer (score 0):

Check if toJSON is defined on your object. If it is defined, it can modify the behavior of stringify.